# Exception not being caught by first catch, and instead get handled by a top level catch

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, exception, cancellation

I have a class called `SearchProbe` for I'm writing unit tests. One unit test is for testing the ability of my class's main processing method (called `RunSearchProbe`) to be able to respond to `CancellationTokens` correctly. My class's main processing method executes async submethods which all throw an `OperationCanceledException` when a `CancellationToken` is cancelled. Then in my main method `RunSearchProbe`, I'm trying to catch this exception and respond to it.

**Problem:** The problem is that for some reason, `OperationCanceledException` is NOT being caught in the main method `RunSearchProbe`, and it comes all the way upto my unit test's call stack for handling, and I don't know why ?!

Here's my main class:

```
public class SearchProbe
{
    protected async Task RunSearchProbe(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                using (cancellationToken.Register(() => {
                    //some code here
                }))
                {
                    Task<bool> initTask = Initialize(cancellationToken);
                    await initTask;

                    //some code here
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception) when (exception.GetType().Equals(typeof(OperationCanceledException))
            || exception.InnerException.GetType().Equals(typeof(OperationCanceledException)))
            {
                //some code here // -------->>> (Point 1) This is where the OperationCanceledException SHOULD get caught
            }
            finally
            {
                //some code here
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //some code here  // -------->>> (Point 2) ... Or AT LEAST get caught here
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> Initialize(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        try
        {
            using (cancellationToken.Register(() => {
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }))
            {
                //some code here
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //some code here
        }
    }
}
```

This is a mock inherited class:

```
class MockSearchProbe : SearchProbe
{   
    static MockSearchProbe()
    {
        //some code here
    }

    public async Task RunProbeManually()
    {
        try {

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task probeTask = RunSearchProbe(cts.Token);

        cts.Cancel();

        await probeTask;

        }
        catch (Exception exception) when (exception.GetType().Equals(typeof(OperationCanceledException))
              || exception.InnerException.GetType().Equals(typeof(OperationCanceledException)))
        {
            //do something (Point 3) ... But it actually gets caught here for some reason
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class SearchProbeTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestProbe_Cancellation()
    {
        MockSearchProbe probe = new MockSearchProbe();

        Task result = probe.RunProbeManually();

        await result;
    }
}
```

Please see steps 1, 2 and 3 commented above to see what I mean ... Why is the catch block inside my main class's `RunSearchProbe` method NOT catching the `OperationCanceledException` ??

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=netframework-4.8) for `CancellationToken.Regsiter` states that the method:

> Registers a delegate that will be called when this CancellationToken is canceled.

Based on that description, I would expect that the registration callback defined in the `Initialize` method should execute when `cts.Cancel()` is called in `RunProbeManually`. The exception is not instantiated or thrown until that point, which is in the scope of the try/catch block labeled "Point 3."

Here's a simplified illustration:

```cs
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    Action throwException = null;

    try {
      Console.WriteLine("Defining delegate");

      throwException = () => {
        Console.WriteLine("Throwing exception");
        throw new Exception();
      };

    } catch (Exception) {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception caught at point 1");
    }

    try {
      Console.WriteLine("Invoking delegate");

      throwException.Invoke();
    } catch (Exception) {
      Console.WriteLine ("Exception caught at point 2");
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Defining delegate
Invoking delegate
Throwing exception
Exception caught at point 2
```